# How to count the total number of windows excluding some buftype?

Tags: vimscript

As title. Some floating windows will have buffer type (`buftype`) value `nofile`, I don't want to count them! How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more efficient way to do it but this should work:

```
" initialize count variable
let g:cnt = 0

" run test for each window incrementing count when appropriate
windo if &buftype !=# 'nofile' | let g:cnt += 1 | endif

" then, for example, we could display the count
echo g:cnt
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way that doesn't use `:windo`

```
:echo tabpagebuflist()->filter({_, v -> getbufvar(v, '&buftype') isnot# 'nofile' })->len()
```

(My original solution used `map()` to get the `buftype` and then `filter()` on that list; the advantage of combining them is that, if you were interested in other things than `len()`, you would still have the buffer numbers after the filter.)

The equivalent *sans* lambdas is

```
:echo tabpagebuflist()->filter("getbufvar(v:val, '&buftype') isnot# 'nofile'")->len()
```

---

This will count windows, since `tabpagebuflist()` returns a buffer-number for each window (even when two windows show the same buffer). If you only care about the number of unique buffers in windows, throw a `->uniq()` after `tabpagebuflist()`.

Comment: Ah, sorry, need more coffee! I wonder between Vim lambdas and arrow notation, which of them is older? If you're going for compatibility, I wonder if translating arrows wouldn't be worth it?

Comment: I was motivated by performance, mostly: in simple tests I’ve seen lambdas be 2–3x slower, but I like them for how readable they are.

Comment: Wow I would imagine the opposite, regarding performance! Answering my own question, lambdas were introduced in 7.4.2044 (essentially Vim 8.0) and methods were introduced in 8.1.1803 (essentially Vim 8.2).